# Casting ArrayList<File> into java.io.File Error

Tags: android, file, arraylist, casting

I have an `ArrayList` of `Images`

```
private final ArrayList<File> images;
```

It seems when I recreate the images from the `Bundle` I get the `ClassCastException`:

```
public DocumentJob(@Nullable ArrayList<File> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public DocumentJob(Bundle bundle) {
    this.images = (ArrayList<File>) bundle.getSerializable(BundleKeys.FILENAMES.name());
}

 @Override
public Bundle createBundle() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(BundleKeys.FILENAMES.name(), images);
    return bundle;
}
```

The logs show that the error comes when I try to actually use the list itself after it is recreated from the `Bundle`:

```
    @Override
public void callRestApi(RestApi restApi, RestApiJobService.ApiRequestor apiRequestor) {

    File image = images.get(0); //This is the error line
}
```

But then I get an `Exception` with a message:

```
2020-01-03 16:08:39.606 1386-1386/example.example.com.myApplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.example.com.myApplication, PID: 1386
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.io.File
    at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:112)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.io.File
    at example.example.com.myApplication.model.DocumentJob.callRestApi(DocumentJob.java:82)
    at example.example.com.myApplication.service.RestApiJobService.onStartJob(RestApiJobService.java:81)
    at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:62)
    at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: Alright, will try soon. But is there a reason the foreach loop is not working?

Comment: @blackapps tried doing what you suggested (edited the question) but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @blackapps on this line `File image = images.get(i)`. I also tried removing two last lines from the loop and got the same.

Comment: @blackapps edited the question.. it seems like I was looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205417/discussion-between-kataroty-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps Changed the question

Comment: You are not showing where you use the bundle from createBundle.

Comment: Why a second constructor if the first does it?

Comment: @blackapps basically I am first creating it from the first constructor without using bundle and then when I create a `Job` to call the `restApi` I put it into a bundle and make the api call using the bundle in case I need to repeat the `restApi` call. So first the first constructor is used. Then I create the bundle, and start the api call using the second.. bundle constructor.

Comment: Your only problem is how to put your list in a bundle and get it out again. You could demonstrate your problem without using constructors or parameters. With far less code yet again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the answer here was to use `ArrayList<String> imagePaths` instead of the `images` themselves and then once they are unbundeled, get the images back using those paths.

```
private ArrayList<String> imagePaths;

    @Override
public Bundle createBundle() {
    bundle.putStringArrayList(BundleKeys.FILENAMES.name(), imagePaths);
    ...

public InstallationDocumentJob(Bundle bundle) {
    this.imagePaths = bundle.getStringArrayList(BundleKeys.FILENAMES.name());
    ArrayList<File> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    assert imagePaths != null;
    for (String imagePath: imagePaths) {
        if (imagePath != null) {
            imageList.add(new File(imagePath));
        }
    }
    this.images = imageList;
}
```

I am not sure if this is the completely correct approach, but it seems to do the trick.